# About the definition of regular surface in do Carmo

Tags: differential-geometry

According to do Carmo, the definition of regular surface requires us to check $X^{-1}$ to be continuous (where $X$ is a local parametrization). But doesn't it infer from other conditions (as shown in his Prop. 4 of Sec 2-2, see photo attached [here !!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7c80.jpg))? Although he stated regular surface has to be known in advance (prop. 4), actually it seems that he doesn't use it in the proof. He simply uses $X$ to be differentiable and regular and inverse function theorem to conclude $X^{-1}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\Param}{\mathbf{x}}$It's difficult to answer fully since "Conditions 1 and 3 of Definition 1" are on a different page than shown in your photograph, but the usual reason for requiring $\Param^{-1}$ to be continuous is to avoid examples such as
$$
\Param(u, v) = (\sin u, \sin 2u, v),\quad -\pi < u < \pi,\ 0 < v < 1,
$$
an injective regular map whose image is not a surface:

[image: An injective parametrization whose image is not a surface]